# Using Export-ModuleMember to export a script as a function or alias

Tags: powershell

I have a module in which I am trying to export a function/alias. The item I am trying to export is a script file foo.ps1 which does not declare a named function, but I want to export it as available in the session as being able to invoke foo. Is this supported? If so, how do I configure the Export-ModuleMember call?

Here is a snippet from the very top of the file:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='default')]
param(
  [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage="You must specify which task to     execute.")]
  [ValidateSet('install','update', 'uninstall', 'outdated', 'init', 'help', '?')]
  ....
```

There are no function definitions. Rather the function name is the file name.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to load the script contents into a ScriptBlock and create a function out of it.

```
[string]$content = Get-Content $here\foo.ps1 -Delimiter ([Environment]::NewLine)
$block = [ScriptBlock]::Create($content)
Invoke-Expression "function foo { $block }"
Export-ModuleMember -function foo
```

This works, but is far from ideal.

Comment: I was about to suggest, it is not ideal but it is the only why I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try to dot-source the script in the module psm1 file and the use `Export-ModuleMember` to export its function(s).

Comment: dot-sourcing the script executes it which I don't want.

Comment: If the script contains functions/aliases nothing is executed, content should import into the module scope.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PS II> # UNTESTED
PS II> $excmd = gcm G:\inventory.ps1
PS II> set-item function:$($excmd.name.replace('.','_')) -val $excmd.scriptblock
PS II> inventory_ps1
```